# Where System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager points to when there is no configuration file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a solution with many Windows Service projects and a Class Library project that I use to access a MySql database.
In this Class Library project there's a class that does this to retrieve a connection string(I didn't write this code and I'm not sure if it ever worked):

```
Dim strConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MySQLConnection").ToString()
```

When this line is executed, I got a null reference exception. When debugging I realized that it finds two other connection strings, but not the `MySQLConnection`. I could just put the connection string I want in the configuration file, right. But the problem is there is no configuration file inside this project, I don't know where the two connections are coming from.

Comment: There is a hierarchy of configuration files. Maybe in your project there is another config file in a parent folder? Check this link out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685(v=vs.100).aspx (ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance)

Comment: I have tried that but searching Entire Solution in Visual Studio, but haven't found nothing. However I have realized what was going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a machine.config file which is at the top of the configuration merge hierarchy.  Next there is the web.config (found in the same place as the machine.config). The web.config files, if it existed, would be the third file found by your web application.   For more info, read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#configuration_inheritance).

Comment: Right, but as I said there were no configuration files in any of my projects and I do not have a web application in my solution.

Comment: The machine.config and web.config files I'm referring to have nothing to do with your project or solution.  These files (among others) can be found in directories such as C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config.  You will have  a set of config files for each version of the Framework on your machine.  When your project runs, it looks here first.

Comment: Oh, you're right! The application was getting that default connection string from the machine.config file in the directory you said. I just didn't understand what you were saying. Thank you (: